# Python directory for pip package not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a pip package but I can't import stuff from the file 'src'?
I think it might be something with **init**.py but im not sure why.

Here is my directory:

```
./
├── dist
│   └── robloxapi-0.9.tar.gz
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST
├── README.md
├── robloxapi
│   ├── client.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── src
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── Auth.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   ├── request.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   ├── User.cpython-37.pyc
│       │   └── xcsrf.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── request.py
│       ├── User.py
│       └── xcsrf.py
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

here is what I am importing in my main file (client.py)

```
import requests
from .src.User import User
```

When I try import `.src.User` it returnes an error.

witch is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 1, in <module>
    import robloxapi
  File "/home/ira/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robloxapi/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import client
  File "/home/ira/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robloxapi/client.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .src.User import User
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robloxapi.src'
```

Why am I unable to import this?

Thanks, Ira.

Edit:
`Setup.py`: https://hastebin.com/tonalezeva.coffeescript
`setup.cfg`: https://hastebin.com/ovehukociz.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that was raised `ModuleNotFoundError` indicates that python is trying to import `robloxapi.src` as a module.

According to your project structure, the directory should be a python package, but it is not because it is missing an `__init__.py` file.

Creating a file at `robloxapi/src/__init__.py` (which can also be left empty) should resolve this issue.

Quoting the [official python docs about modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

## Edit

After I've looked at your setup.py file I believe that the problem is that you do not specify the sub-packages in your project in the `packages` list passed to the setup function.

I also noticed you are using distutils, I highly recommend you install and use the setuptools package which is a highly popular extension to the built in distutils package.

One of setuptools great features is the `find_packages` function which saves the burden of managing the packages to be distributed manually

Heres a reference to the setuptools docs:

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#id10

Comment: I added a __init__.py still did not work
so i looked at the package location file using `pip show mypackage`

And here i can't even see a src file?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you've installed the package and how you are executing the script?

Comment: Im installing with `pip install packagename`
and im just trying to get it to work so i have this code

import robloxapi
print(robloxapi)

Comment: Could you update your question with the contents of setup.py and setup.cfg